# Swift: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, NSObject

Tags: ios, swift

Using Swift 2 and Xcode 7 in an IOS app, I'm trying to avoid the `fatal error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` applying the optional chaining to a FriendShip NSObject but I don't know which is the correct way.

The class FriendShip showed below receives a nil value in the friend property but the compiler gives me the `fatal error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`:

```js
class FriendShip: NSObject{

  var id: String?
  var friend: User?
  var date: NSDate?

  init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]){

    id        = dictionary["id"] as? String
    friend    = User(dictionary: (dictionary["friend"] as! [String: AnyObject]))
    date      = dictionary["date"] as? NSDate

  }
}
```

but if I set the friend property to optional, the compiler gives me an
`EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error:

```js
class FriendShip: NSObject{

  var id: String?
  var friend: User?
  var date: NSDate?

  init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]){

    id        = dictionary["id"] as? String
    friend    = User(dictionary: (dictionary["friend"] as? [String: AnyObject])!)
    date      = dictionary["date"] as? NSDate

  }
}
```

How could I solve it?

Comment: on great thing about swift.  Where's the bug? It's where the exclamation mark is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're still unwrapping an optional here:

```
friend    = User(dictionary: (dictionary["friend"] as? [String: AnyObject])!)
```

Namely:

```
(dictionary["friend"] as? [String: AnyObject])!
```

This should be instead something like:

```
if let friendDictionary = dictionary["friend"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
    friend = User(dictionary:friendDictionary)
}
```